# Getting values from multiple text boxes on keypress in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have 8 different text fields in my form, it's a part of customer bill.
Here it is

```
<input type="text" name="txtcustomduty" class="form-control" placeholder="Customs Duty">
<input type="text"  name="txtlcltranspotation" class="form-control" placeholder="Local Transportation">
......

up to 8
```

From this I want to show the sum of all the values as total value

```
<span>Total extra cost:1678</span>
```

It should be changed when the values of any text field is changed, so how can I do it perfectly using `keyup` event?

**UPDATE**

I have attached an onkeyup event to each textfield

```
`onkeyup="findSum(this.value)"'
```

and i am using a global array for store the input values `var extras=[]`

```
function findSum(value)
{
    if(value!=''){
        console.log(value);
        extras.push(parseInt(value));
        if(extras!='')
        $('#extratotal').text(extras.reduce(getSum));
        else $('#extratotal').text('0');
    }
}
```

But its not worked well

Comment: Great question, but what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get SUM of all inputs that have `form-control` class on `keyup` event like this:

```js
$('input.form-control').on('keyup',function() {   
    var total = 0;
    $('input.form-control').each(function(){
        if (this.value == ''){
            total += parseInt(0);
        }else{
            total += parseInt(this.value);
        }
    });
    $('#total').val(total);
});
```

```css
input {
   display: block;   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="txtcustomduty" class="form-control" placeholder="Customs Duty" >
<input type="text"  name="txtlcltranspotation" class="form-control" placeholder="Local Transportation" >
<input type="text"  name="other" class="form-control" placeholder="other" >

Total extra cost: <input id="total" >
```

Comment: Worked partially but getting `NAn`

Comment: @BlessanKurien Very odd, it works perfectly for me, have you filled all inputs with valid values?

Comment: Yes i filled up with numeric

Comment: Its worked dude:) actually its my mistake ,i've typo in my class name

Comment: @BlessanKurien that's nice, glad to help you :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `target.value` property of the event passed to the key listener - this will give you the value of the input field:

```
document.addEventListener('input', 'keyup', function(e) {
    // use e.target.value here
}
```

Just add this to a running total and update the text inside the listener function.

Answer (score 1):

I have defined in JavaScript instead of jQuery. Try it..

```
<script>
function sum()
{

    var sum = 0;
    var array_field = document.getElementsByClassName('sum_field');
    for(var i=0; i<array_field.length; i++)
    {
         var value = Number(array_field[i].value);
         if (!isNaN(value)) sum += value;
    }
    document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = sum;
 }
</script>
<body>
    <input type="text" name="txtcustomduty" class="form-control sum_field" placeholder="Customs Duty" onkeyup="sum()">
    <input type="text"  name="txtlcltranspotation" class="form-control sum_field" placeholder="Local Transportation" onkeyup="sum()">
    <p>Total:<span id="total">0</span></p>
</body>
```